# unable to edit footer area in magento

Tags: magento

I am a newbie in magento. I want to replace the footer area in magento default theme with just an image and for this I edited the footer.phtml file. I removed all the links Contact Us and etc. But how to replace the default blue image from the bottom that is seen on the magento home page using default theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to edit the CSS for the default theme in that case. Also, depending on how you want the footer to look you should also edit the footer html code to fit your design requirements.

Assuming you are using the completely default theme, check this css file for the .footer tags:

skin/frontend/default/default/css/style.css

You can change all your CSS there.

Comment: I tried to edit the footer tag in css but that blue image in footer area still remains. Can u tell me from where is this blue image coming in.

Answer (score -1):

Would suggest you first activate Template hints from System>Configuration>Developer>

Now look at the footer area to see from which theme the footer.phtml is being loaded. Edit the related CSS and you should be good to go

Would also suggest you empty the Magento Cache after making any css changes as suggested